# v-carousel is responsive but not the images it contains

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

When I use [v-carousel](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels), everything works fine, except I noticed on mobile even if the carousel itself is responsive, the images inside it are not, so only the middle portion of each picture is shown:

```
 <v-carousel hide-delimiters>
    <v-carousel-item
       v-for="(item,i) in items"
       :key="i"
       :src="item.src"
     ></v-carousel-item>
 </v-carousel>
```

How can I overcome this problem? I want to see the images inside the carousel to be responsive also.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out v-carousel and it looks like they're `div`s with the images set as the background image, so you're looking for the `background-size` css and have it set to `background-size: cover` and you should be set. For more details, check out W3 [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

EDIT:
Looking more into v-carousel, it looks like the image formatting is set up in the API [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/images#contain-and-cover)

Comment: I gave it a try with `active-class` set to the CSS class defined as you said, but it does not work. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: Does this seem to be browser specific?

Comment: I tried both `aspect-ratio` and `active-class` but no result. Any example provided here in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels) can be used to play with online directly.

Comment: Yes, I did that too

Comment: If `contain` is true, then it will crop the images

Comment: Try doing this in your css: `.v-image__image{ background-size: cover }` and see what happens.

Comment: Not a very clean attempt, but I tried it now that you asked, it does not take effect either. Thank you

Comment: Do you have an example I can view on my mobile device that doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not provide a link to try directly on the mobile, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how v-carousel works, however, just looking at the html generated the carousel is using **background images** and this prevents your image to be responsive.

I suggest you to change carousel or search for an option that lets you change the way that the image is placed.

With an img tag you can set in your css `max-width: 100%` and your image will be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height="auto"` on the `<v-carousel>` like so:

```
<v-carousel height="auto" hide-delimiters>
```

The carousel will then become responsive and image will shrink according to your container / screen width.

Answer (score 0):

I checked `v-carousel-item` and I found it's an image and then with checking the `v-img` in vuetify, I found with adding `contain` to `v-carousel-item`, you can force the image to show all areas and prevent the image from being cropped if it doesn't fit. your code should change to this:

```
<v-carousel hide-delimiters>
    <v-carousel-item
       v-for="(item,i) in items"
       :key="i"
       :src="item.src"
       contain
     ></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```